# How to get a prop value into a function from a Class in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react app with several API calls. I have a component and inside the component, I have a Class and a function outside the class. This component is a child one and receive some props from its parent. My API call is going in the outside function which is getSuggestionValue and that API call need a prop (jobId) coming from the parent class. **The problem is I'm having the error
`Cannot read property 'projectdata' of undefined`**

```
function getSuggestionValue(suggestion) {

    const job_id = this.props.projectdata.jobId;
    const user_id = suggestion.id;

    API.post('job/assign_user', { job_id, user_id })
        .then(({ data }) => {
            console.log("success!", data)
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
        })
    return suggestion.label;
}

class ProjectModal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            status: null
        };
    }

    render() {

      const autosuggestProps = {
        getSuggestionValue
      };

      return(
        <div>{this.props.projectdata.jobId}
         <Autosuggest
          {...autosuggestProps}
          //other props
         />
        </div>

        //other function calls
      )
    }
}
```

I know that the problems is here

```
const job_id = this.props.projectdata.jobId;
```

in the getSuggestionValue function, but have no idea how to put the jobId to the API call. How can I do this?

Comment: Where are you calling `getSuggestionValue`?

Comment: Is your property typeof an object? Otherwise, accessing it like ```this.props.projectdata.jobId```would return undefined.

Comment: @DrazenBjelovuk I'm calling it inside the render function. I updated my code

Comment: @k3lly.dev it is an object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap your function:

```
const getSuggestionValue = (props) => (suggestion) => {

    const job_id = props.projectdata.jobId;
    const user_id = suggestion.id;
    ...
```

```
  const autosuggestProps = {
    getSuggestionValue: getSuggestionValue(this.props)
  };
```

Or pass down `projectdata` as a prop into your nested component, and include it as a parameter:

```
function getSuggestionValue(projectdata, suggestion) {

    const job_id = projectdata.jobId;
    const user_id = suggestion.id;
    ...
```

```
  const autosuggestProps = {
    getSuggestionValue,
    projectdata: this.props.projectdata
  };
```

But at that point, doesn't make a whole lot of sense to be passing the function itself as a property to begin with. You should consider simply referencing it statically from `Autosuggest`.

Answer (score 0):

As your this.props are undefined so that is the reason you get Cannot read property 'projectdata' of undefined. So what you can do is pass second param to the function like this.

> getSuggestionValue(suggestion, props)

**this** inside the function resolve "this" of that function.

wherever you are calling getSuggestionValue function call like below:-

> getSuggestionValue(suggestion, this.props) {
>     const job_id = props.projectdata.jobId;
>   }

I suppose you are calling the above function inside the class.

Comment: I updated my code. I'm calling the function inside the render method

Comment: If you are calling inside the class then pass the props to the function. Like this -> getSuggestionValue(suggestion, this.props)